# How do nested if-Statements in JS work?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, nested

I got a problem with nested if-statements in JS. Let me show you the code example:

```
    if (code < 699) {
        if(hour > 6 && hour < 20) {
            $("#weatherIcon").html("<i class='wi wi-day-" + icon + "'></i>");
        }
        else {
            if(icon == "sunny") {
                $("#weatherIcon").html("<i class='wi wi-night-clear'></i>");
            }
                $("#weatherIcon").html("<i class='wi wi-night-alt-" + icon + "'></i>");
            }
        }

        $("#weatherIcon").html("<i class='wi wi-" + icon + "'></i>");
   }
```

I added a print statement so I can check the values for `code`, `hour` and `icon` (values are `502`, `17` and `rain-mix`) so I should get `<i class='wi wi-day-sunny'></i>` returned but I always end up in the last line so that the output is e.g. `<i class='wi wi-sunny'></i>` Why is that? What am I not seeing? 
Any help very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: becuse the line after the if will run and override the code in the if....

Comment: You have an extra `}` in the code you shared.

Comment: There is a missing `else` in the if icon.... also in your attached code, as long as `code < 699`, then `$("#weatherIcon").html("<i class='wi wi-" + icon + "'></i>");` will execute as the last statement and will override your other `.html()` statements

Comment: Thanks @epascarello, didn't know that if always requires else (I am coming from python so ...).

Comment: I just copied a tiny part of the code so might missed a ```}```. Thanks anyways, @krillgar

Comment: I actually modified the if-condition to bring it down to a minimum to see if it works but as I already said earlier: wasn't aware that if- always requires else as well. Thanks, @huangism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code after the if, always overwrite whatever inside the if, you should use else, or just move it before the if to let the if overwrite whatever is the default. Try the following:

```
if (code < 699) {
  if (hour > 6 && hour < 20) {
    $("#weatherIcon").html("<i class='wi wi-day-" + icon + "'></i>");
  } else {
    if (icon == "sunny") {
      $("#weatherIcon").html("<i class='wi wi-night-clear'></i>");
    } else {
      $("#weatherIcon").html("<i class='wi wi-night-alt-" + icon + "'></i>");
    }
  }
} else {
  $("#weatherIcon").html("<i class='wi wi-" + icon + "'></i>");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @daniel-h  I just knew from Python that you can write an if-statement with the else part so I assumed the same goes for JS. I guess I was wrong ... another question: why do I get downgraded? Was the question that stupid!?

Comment: @MickeyMahoney not me downgrading you but there are haters everywhere lool

Comment: makes it very easy for newbies to post here. Anyways, thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 0):

You probably *are* entering that `if` block, just like you wanted. Immediately after that, you're running the last line as well.

Consider, analogously, if you did

```
if(foo) {
   bar = 7
}
bar = 0;
```

`bar` will always by `0` at the end of that code. If `foo` is true, then `bar` will very briefly by `7`, and then immediately get set to `0`.

If you really want that line to run when `code < 699` fails, instead of all the time, put it inside of `else` block under the outermost `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not set a default class and change the class based on your conditions?

```js
let code = 502;
let hour = 17;
let iconClass = 'wi-rain-mix';

if (code < 699) {
  if (hour > 6 && hour < 20) {
    iconClass = 'wi-day-rain-mix';
  } else {
    if (icon == "sunny") {
      iconClass = 'wi-night-clear';
    } else {
      iconClass = 'wi-night-alt-rain-mix';
    }
  }
}
$("#weatherIcon").html("<i class='wi " + iconClass + "'></i>");
// Check the weather class..
console.log($('.wi').attr('class'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="weatherIcon"></div>
```